# Reference variable from another ini section

Tags: python, ini

Is it possible to reference a variable within an ini from another section?

I know you can do the following

```
[env]
dir  = /home/a
dir2 = %(dir)s/b
```

But what happens if I have two sections and want to reference the variable from that section?

```
[env]
name =  DEV

[dir]
home = /home/<name from env here>/scripts
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

See the documentation on [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#interpolation-of-values). Create a parser with extended interpolation. Use `${section:option}` syntax to reference options from other sections.

```python3
from configparser import ConfigParser, ExtendedInterpolation

parser = ConfigParser(interpolation=ExtendedInterpolation())
parser.read_string('''[env]
name = DEV

[dir]
home = /home/${env:name}/scripts
''')

print(parser['dir']['home'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.x not support cross ref. from another section.

But you can use [DEFAULT]. The definitions in this section are shareable specially.