# ini file - Refer variable from another ini file

Tags: ini

How can I parse variable from another ini file?

In following example, I'd like to parse `var_a` from *`original_configuration.ini`* and use it at *`new_configuration.ini`*

*original_configuration.ini*:

```
[Section A]

var_a = "foo"

var_b = "bar"
```

*new_configuration.ini*:

```
[Section B]

var_c = "lorem"

var_d = {value of var_a in original_configuration.ini}
```

Comment: Please add a bit more details to your question. Like what you have tried, and what language you are using. Also see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @agold It's not related with any language. It's just about .ini file. Why do you think this question have insufficient info?

Comment: Since you mentioned 'parse' I thought you wanted to retrieve the values with a script. So you want to refer in the new_configuration.ini to a variable in original_configuration.ini?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Thanks for your comment. I'll edit the word 'parse' to 'refer'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since an [INI file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) is an **informal standard** it depends on the program which is using the configuration file:

> The INI file format is an informal standard for configuration files for some platforms or software. INI files are simple text files with a basic structure composed of sections, properties, and values.

Neither [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) nor [Microsoft's page about INI configutariont files](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731332.aspx) mention anything about referring to other properties or other configuration files. However since it is not a formal standard, each configuration parser can have its own variant. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25051295/1771479) for example, shows that Python's [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/configparser.html#interpolation-of-values) package is able to refer to other properties:

```
[env]
name = DEV

[dir]
home = /home/${env:name}/scripts
```

Comment: I tried this in my `ini file` but it is not working. I named my sections randomly as `[files]` & `[tool]` and the options too. But when trying to set the value of the `ofile` option in `[files]` to equal a value of the `cmd` option in `[tool]` section following your syntax, it doesn't work !!

Comment: Maybe you should ask a separate question giving all the details.